# Am I allowed to thank people in comments?

Tags: discussion, comments

As the title says. I feel like it should be ok as long as it's not in the answer, but thanking people and generally adding unnecessary stuff (as opposed to things that are directly related to the question) seem discouraged here, so I'm just asking to make sure.

Comment: As a side note, being against noise is one of SE's ideals. You can always socialize with people on [chat], providing that they also agree and visit there. Treat SE like it's your most special notebook and no chatter is allowed in it.

Answer (score 8):

Thank you for asking this.

A comment like "+1, this helped me a lot, thanks!" is discouraged, per the [help center](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers):

> **Please do not add a comment on your question or on an answer to say "Thank you".** Comments are meant for requesting clarification, leaving constructive criticism, or adding relevant but minor additional information – not for socializing. If you want to say "thank you," vote on or accept that person's answer, or simply pay it forward by providing a great answer to someone else's question.

The *built-in* way to say "thank you" is voting up (which requires 15 reputation due to irrelevant but important reasons) or accepting the answer (if it answered your question adequately). Thanking the author is noise, and I seriously recommend considering commenting only when

- you have some clarifications to do about the answer.
- you have further insight that's useful for other people to read. *About the question or the answer*.
- you believe something else needs to be issued about the answer, e.g. it's wrong etc.

**Don't** comment when

- you want to start a chat with the answerer.
- you have another question, even if it's related to the subject.
- you have something to say that isn't relevant.
- you need some help with using the site's features.

Comment: Thanks for this answer!

Comment: @Ortho ◟(`ﮧ´ ◟ )Oɹʇɥoɔɹǝsoꞁ [(┛◉Д◉)┛彡┻━┻](http://i.imgur.com/JWumYHu.gif)

Comment: Can i assume that the Chemistry Meta (and other SE Meta pages) is more lenient about this?

Comment: Yes @name.disp; as well demonstrated by @Ortho, having a bit of fun is allowed on metas. Heck, meta sites are all about discussion, and as long as fun doesn't distract from the main topic, it's allowed.

Answer (score 5):

Of course you can. People do it all the time.

You should remember that it is not recommended by the SE team. It is also often perceived as clutter and/or noise. Maybe your comment will be flagged and then deleted. If that is the case, please don’t be angry. Understand that comments are not meant for eternity.

And also remember, as the German saying goes: You never eat the food as hot as it is cooked ;)

Comment: What does the proverb mean? Possible guesses are "Your comment is not as good as you think." "SE isn't as noiseless as it looks." "I hate the food I'm eating right now." "Your comment isn't hot and hence we'll burn it so it becomes hot." "German sausages and beer"

Comment: @TIPS ‘We don’t take the rules as literally as they are written.’

Comment: I think these comments are fine, as I've left them myself, but it helps to delete them after a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: Personally, I actually appreciate it whenever someone writes a "Thank you" comment on any of my answers. Sure, it doesn't contribute to the discussion, but I think it encourages the answerer to keep answering.

Comment: @tima yes, sometimes a "thank you" feels better than an upvote and accept combined. It would've been really okay if people deleted these comments after a while though, since after a year, when I land on your question, I don't need to see you thanking someone else. Sadly, people don't delete them, and in the mean time, they make the site look messy and noisy.

Comment: But that’s okay: Free flags ;)

Comment: The German proverb alone earned my upvote!  How is it said in German?  I've never heard that before, and I can't find *any* references to your translation.

Comment: @feetwet ‘Es wird nichts so heiß gegessen, wie es gekocht wird.’